# IParameterInspector Identify a REST Service

Tags: wcf

I am planning to add a WCF Behavior to all the web services(SOAP + REST) in my solution.
I plan to use the same IParameterInspector implementation.
Is there a way in the implementation I can identify if the request call is for a WCF service or REST Service.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution as below

//To Identify if it is a REST Service. 
//Action will be null in case of REST Service

bool isRestService = string.IsNullOrEmpty(OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.Action);